# Restrict special variable in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to restrict getGatewaySerialNumber from taking special characters.

I have written these condition but if block it is executing only first condition it is not checking for and condition.

How to restrict Gatewayserialnumber from taking special character.

```
If(manifestRequestEntity.getGatewaySerialNumber().lenghth()>16 && manifestRequestEntity.getGatewaySerialNumber().matches(regex :"[0-9a-fA-F]+"))
```

Comment: `lenghth` : typo ; `matches(regex :"[0-9a-fA-F]+")` : the `regex: ` part shouldn't be there. This code shouldn't compile, the behaviour you're seeing must be from previous versions of the code.

Comment: Also, the `If` is upper case. This is **clearly** not the code that you actually compiled. When asking about code, don't post code that *roughly approximates* what you're doing: Post the exact code that is causing problems.

Comment: Why not merge the first part  `manifestRequestEntity.getGatewaySerialNumber().lenghth()  > 16` into second regex part as one condition , like this : `manifestRequestEntity.getGatewaySerialNumber().matches(regex :"[0-9a-fA-F]{17,}")`

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
  name = "abc";
  Pattern special= Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Pattern number = Pattern.compile("[0-9]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = special.matcher(name);
  Matcher matcherNumber = number.matcher(name);

  boolean constainsSymbols = matcher.find();
  boolean containsNumber = matcherNumber.find();

  if(constainsSymbols){
   //string contains special symbol/character
  }
  else if(containsNumber){
   //string contains numbers
  }
  else{
   //string doesn't contain special characters or numbers
  }
```

Comment: `containsSymbols == true` is useless noise. Just write `if(containsSymbols)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some helper methods to check if it only contains alphabets and numbers

something like this :

```
    public static boolean checkForSpecialChar(String stringToCheck){

            char ch[] = stringToCheck.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0; i<ch.length; i++)
            {
                if((ch[i]>='A' && ch[i]<='Z') || (ch[i]>='a' && ch[i]<='z') || (ch[i]>='0' && ch[i]<='9'))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: If you insist on doing this manually, at least use char constants (`'0'`, `'9'`) instead of their numeric values. This code is basically impossible to verify for correctness unless you know the Unicode codepoints of these common characters by hearth.

Comment: well i said "try something like this", i was just giving an idea, yeah as you said we can use char constants.